# Deploy a web application to a test server

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

In our small team we are using Visual Studio 2015 and Team Foundation Server 2015.

We develop on our laptops, we have a couple of servers where we do some test and finally we have a production environment on Azure.

Developers' laptops and test servers are on the same network and part of the same domain.

At the moment we build our web applications (based on C# + AngularJS + WebAPI), then we manually copy files on test server (dll and other files) where IIS is installed. Then we browse to a URL and check our application.

I hope there is a smarter way to do this automatically, a more professional way to deploy file from Visual Studio (or from TFS) to a test environment. I've googled for a while but I did not find a good (and simple) solution...maybe i'm not good googleing.

Could you suggest me a best practice to follow in this scenarios?

Comment: Have you searched for WebDeploy in SO?

Comment: Which TFS version do you use?

Answer (score -1):

We used to do this initially and found that we cannot afford to do this manually due to time it takes plus we want repeatability.
So we invested some time in looking for a product and found one: "Jenkins" and it is free.
We started using Jenkins which does all the checkout from a repository, compiling and build and sending it to the server automatically to your Test server. We had written scripts to copy files from one computer to another.
We are now in a phase where we are automating the tests.
Once you start building a mock up you will find it so easy to use plus lots of help in the Internet. You can create lots of small Build projects and combine the outputs for your final solution.
There are lots of documentation and help available on the web.

As a basic requirement:

1) All source code should be in a repository like SVN or others like Source Safe, Team Foundation, Git server etc.

2) Use a "clean" machine which hasn't been installed with any software apart from one that are needed. This will be used as your build machine by Jenkins.

3) Start virtualising your Build machine. This way you can create a snapshot of the clean machine. The build job can revert to this "clean" state at the start of the new build job automatically.

So in a typical scenario a developer checks-in their code. Jenkins can be configure to automatically trigger a build (Continuous Integration) when a new code is checked in a repository.
When the Build finishes (if the scripts are written correctly) your Test server will have the solution installed. The Developer can then perform the module tests on the actual machine.

So if you invest some time learning how to configure and use Jenkins to create build jobs, this is one of the best ones in the market.